# How to detect whether a type is std::tuple or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Why I have strange output for this code? How to test for a type in the right way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> struct is_tuple : std::false_type {};
template<typename... Ts> struct is_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

struct TraitBlock {
    using BlockLocation = struct { std::uint64_t x, y, z; };
};

struct TraitRock {};

struct ItemTemplate{
    static constexpr auto traits = std::make_tuple(
        TraitBlock{},
        TraitRock{}
    );
};

int main(){
    using A = std::tuple<char, int,double,char>;
    std::cout << is_tuple<decltype(ItemTemplate::traits)>::value 
    << is_tuple<decltype(std::make_tuple(
        TraitBlock{},
        TraitRock{}
    ))>::value
    << std::endl;
}
```

I use mingw64-gcc 7.2.0 with -std=c++17, I got output "01"
Why I got two different output? Aren't they the same type?

Comment: You might use something like `template <typename> struct Dummy;
template struct Dummy<decltype(ItemTemplate::traits)>;` to let compiler gives you the type in error message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that the type of `ItemTemplate::traits` (i.e. `decltype(ItemTemplate::traits)`) is `const std::tuple<TraitBlock, TraitRock>`, which doesn't match the specified type (i.e. `std::tuple<Ts...>`) in the specialization of `is_tuple`.

You can remove the const-ness by [std::remove_const](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv), e.g.

```
std::cout << is_tuple<std::remove_const_t<decltype(ItemTemplate::traits)>>::value;
```

or add another specialization for `const` (and might `volatile` as well):

```
template<typename... Ts> struct is_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
template<typename... Ts> struct is_tuple<const std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
template<typename... Ts> struct is_tuple<volatile std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
template<typename... Ts> struct is_tuple<const volatile std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
```

Answer (score 16):

`decltype(ItemTemplate::traits)` is `const std::tuple<TraitBlock, TraitRock>`.

So you have to handle cv qualifier somewhere.

Comment: Oh, constexpr implies const, but When I use constexpr, will it also make inner types of make_tuple const?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you have `const std::tuple<TraitBlock, TraitRock>`, not `const std::tuple<const TraitBlock, const TraitRock>`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to remove all qualifiers. Instead of doing this all yourself you should use `std::decay_t` which removes all qualifiers for you and dispatch to your trait. For instance

```
template<typename T>
struct is_tuple_impl : std::false_type {};

template<typename... Ts>
struct is_tuple_impl<std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_tuple : is_tuple_impl<std::decay_t<T>> {}
```

Comment: don't you mean `std::remove_cv_t` instead of `std::decay_t`?

Comment: It depends, `remove_cv_t` is a subset of `decay_t`. The latter will as well remove references (r- and l-values) which is usually required for traits as well. Unless you don't want to find `std::tuple<…>&` and `std::tuple<…>&&`.

Comment: Typically, we don't consider `std::tuple<>&` to be a tuple. That's the usual way traits work.